# How to auto-attach vscode-debugger to vue-cli process

Tags: vue.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vue-cli

I am trying to use the auto-attach feature of VSCode(version 1.50.1) to debug my vue app (vue-cli version": "4.3.1").
Like it is explained here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach-feature

My OS is Widows 10

In VSCode `Auto Attach` is set to to `only with Flag`.

I start my app with `npm run dev`.
This is how the `dev` command looks like in my `package.json`:

```
node --inspect --max_old_space_size=2048 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve
```

When i run `npm run dev`, the terminal prints: 
 `Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2fa6ba43-dfa9-41cf-be5d-f0fc8945f02a` 
and:
`Debugger attached`

The Blue Bar on the bottom of VSCode turns orange and it seems like i am debugging.

But when i open the app in my browser (Chrome 86.0.4240.75) my Breakpoints are completely ignored.

I suspect that maybe the problem occurs because i do not access my app on "localhost:8080".
I use xip.io which results in an url like this: `http://example.127.0.0.1.xip.io:8081/`.

Has anyone an idea how to get it runnning?